# Prompted for luks encryption password on boot despite specifying a keyfile

Tags: boot, encryption, cryptsetup

- I have a working installation of Kubuntu 22.04 on a LUKS encrypted
  ext4 partition of device `nvme0n1`. When I boot up my computer, it
  prompts me for the encryption password before proceeding to boot into
  the display manager.
- I have a second hard drive installed in my computer, `sda`, and its
  sole partition `sda1` (ext4) is encrypted with LUKS. I have stored
  the key to this encrypted partition in the file
  `/etc/cryptsetup-keys.d/sda1`.

  - I chose this location because [this
    man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crypttab.5.html)
    said that cryptsetup will automatically look for a keyfile there if I
    don't specify one in the third argument in crypttab. However, it appears that this feature of cryptsetup is not present yet in Kubuntu 22.04 (per `man crypttab` on my machine), so I ended up provided the full path anyway—see below.
- **My goal is to set things up so that whenever I boot Kubuntu, after I enter the
  password to decrypt `nvme0n1p1`, it automatically mounts and decrypts `sda1`.** (♥)

Following [this tutorial](https://averagelinuxuser.com/auto-mount-encrypted-partitions-at-boot/), I modified `/etc/crypttab` as follows:

```
# Entry created by the Kubuntu installer
nvme0n1p4_crypt UUID=aaaaaaaa-****-****-****-********** none luks,discard
# Entry added by me
sda1 UUID=bbbbbbbb-****-****-****-********** /etc/cryptsetup-keys.d/sda1 luks
```

where the UUID for `sda1` is from `sudo cryptsetup luksUUID /dev/sda1`.

(Note that I have explicitly supplied the path to the keyfile. The man page linked above said cryptsetup would check that path if I wrote `none`, but the specific version of cryptsetup that comes with Kubuntu 22.04 appears not to have this feature—it is not mentioned in `man crypttab`.)

Next, I appended the following to `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/mapper/sda1    /mnt/encrypted_sda1 ext4    nofail
```

(The `nofail` option is just to ensure that I can still boot if the decryption or mount sequence fails.)

When I boot up now, I am first prompted for the passkey for `nvme0n1p1`, as expected. When I enter this, there is a brief delay, and then I am asked for the passkey for `sda1`. I can force the system to continue booting by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> a few times, but (needless to say) the drive/partition is not mounted when I get to my session.

- **How can I tell why I am being prompted for the `sda1` passkey?**

  - Is it because my crypttab has a syntax error, or it can't read the file `/etc/cryptsetup-keys.d/sda1`, or the contents of the file are the wrong key, or something else? I don't see anything relevant in `journalctl --boot`.
- **How can I achieve the behavior described above?** (♥)

---

Edit: Didn't realize that `sudo journalctl` gives you more records than just `journalctl`. Found the following relevant lines:

journalctl logs

```
Jan 14 14:36:58 my-computer systemd-cryptsetup[740]: Failed to activate. (Key incorrect?)
Jan 14 14:36:58 my-computer systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch being skipped.
Jan 14 14:36:58 my-computer systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Module efi_pstore...
Jan 14 14:36:58 my-computer systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Plymouth.
Jan 14 14:36:58 my-computer systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Store a System Token in an EFI Variable being skipped.
Jan 14 14:36:58 my-computer systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Commit a transient machine-id on disk being skipped.
Jan 14 14:36:58 my-computer systemd[1]: modprobe@efi_pstore.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 14 14:36:58 my-computer systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module efi_pstore.
Jan 14 14:36:58 my-computer systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Platform Persistent Storage Archival being skipped.
Jan 14 14:37:01 my-computer systemd[1]: systemd-rfkill.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 14 14:37:03 my-computer systemd-cryptsetup[740]: Set cipher aes, mode xts-plain64, key size 512 bits for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/b4130695-c509-426d-93e4-7c645dcd256b.
Jan 14 14:37:05 my-computer systemd-cryptsetup[740]: Failed to activate with specified passphrase. (Passphrase incorrect?)
Jan 14 14:37:06 my-computer systemd-cryptsetup[740]: Set cipher aes, mode xts-plain64, key size 512 bits for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/b4130695-c509-426d-93e4-7c645dcd256b.
Jan 14 14:37:08 my-computer systemd-cryptsetup[740]: Failed to activate with specified passphrase. (Passphrase incorrect?)
Jan 14 14:37:08 my-computer systemd-cryptsetup[740]: Too many attempts to activate; giving up.
Jan 14 14:37:08 my-computer systemd[1]: systemd-cryptsetup@sda1.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 14 14:37:08 my-computer systemd[1]: systemd-cryptsetup@sda1.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 14 14:37:08 my-computer systemd[1]: Failed to start Cryptography Setup for sda1.
Jan 14 14:37:08 my-computer systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Local Encrypted Volumes.
Jan 14 14:37:08 my-computer systemd[1]: cryptsetup.target: Job cryptsetup.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jan 14 14:37:08 my-computer systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /dev/mapper/sda1.
Jan 14 14:37:08 my-computer systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /mnt/encrypted_sda1.
Jan 14 14:37:08 my-computer systemd[1]: mnt-encrypted_sda1.mount: Job mnt-encrypted_sda1.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jan 14 14:37:08 my-computer systemd[1]: dev-mapper-sda1.device: Job dev-mapper-sda1.device/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jan 14 14:37:08 my-computer systemd[1]: systemd-cryptsetup@sda1.service: Consumed 6.159s CPU time.
```

The two `Passphrase incorrect?` entries correspond to me pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> when prompted for the passkey.

---

Edit: Adding the `noearly` option in crypttab also doesn't do anything.

Comment: Try this: start the computer without decrypting the sda1 partition. The in a terminal try the command: `sudo cryptsetup open /dev/sda1 sda1 --key-file /path/to/key`. Replace the second `sda1` and the `/path/to/key` with something and the real path to the key file. Does that decrypt the partition? Update your question with the outcome / error messages.

Comment: Thanks, this got me to the solution. It said the key was wrong. Turns out nano inserted a newline after the passkey. I had even read the bit in the crypttab manual warning about this, and chose nano thinking it didn't have that behavior. Anyway, TIL about `nano -L`.

Comment: How is your filesystem split across these two disks?  Is `sda1` just for `/home/`, or does it have system (`/`) files?

Comment: Neither. `sda1` is just another internal HDD for storing `rsnapshot`s.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be for you to add the passphrase used for `nvme0n1` on the `sda1` device.  In my experience, this has resulted in both disks being decrypted with a single passphrase input.

```
cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/sda1
```

Someone can correct me if I am wrong, but there isn't much benefit in security posture to instead use a keyfile for the second disk found on the first disk.  Instead, this just would just increase your chances of data loss of the second disk if the first becomes faulty or lost.

---

As for using a keyfile, well, that keyfile needs to be available (ie: Decrypted).  Your post doesn't confirm that the first disk is properly decrypted and available at the time of the second disk errors you've shown.

Have you confirmed that the keyfile you've created properly decrypts the disk?  Is it possible you forgot to add this keyfile to the disk, so it's not valid to decrypt the disk?  Stating that you've manually mounted this disk using this keyfile and updating your post would be helpful.

Also, be sure to run the following command after updating `crypttab` to ensure the boot process uses your updated configuration.

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```